# Do I really need a ledger board attached to the house for a deck?

Tags: deck, ledger

I don't want the deck attached to the house. I was thinking free standing. This would remove any flashing needed and leaks etc. Any ideas or suggestions or, reasons this is not a good method?

Comment: How are you going to do five-foot deep footings that are three feet in diameter, zero feet away from your house?

Comment: @Mazura -- one way to solve it is to move the inner footings away from the house, cantilevering the portion of the deck closest to the house as a result

Comment: I have built entire decks that were freestanding on pier blocks (for Mobil/modular homes). The height of the deck also makes a difference with bracing. Check your local requirements as my area requires the deck to be attached at doorways incase of an earthquake so the egress will not separate.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the Building Code that requires a deck be attached to the house.

However, if it is, then the Code requires at least two steel straps near the ends of the deck and attached to the foundation or floor joists.

If you live in a seismically active area or high wind area we know the deck will move differently than the house during an “event”.

Comment: I agree, for a few years if the deck has a small separation from the house that provided a loophole and less electrical was required.

Comment: Is it a problem if they move differently during an event?

Comment: @FreshCodemonger Yes, it’s a problem because they crash into each other and one (usually the light one) gets torn apart.

Answer (score 1):

I've built two decks like this.

One I did pt-6x6 posts epoxy bolted into the basement concrete wall.  This was pseudo free standing as the posts are attached to the house.  The PSL beam that sits on the posts was not (tho it attaches to the posts).  There is a 1" gap between the deck and the exterior of the house.

The other one I did concrete columns with offset footings less than 2' off the ground.  You can cantilever joists and beams to position the closer footings to the house structure.

Answer (score 0):

PORCH DESIGN & CONSTRUCTION GUIDELINES
[www.chicago.gov](https://www.chicago.gov/content/dam/city/depts/bldgs/general/EZPERMIT/PorchGuidelinesMay2011.pdf), PDF.

"specific methods of lateral bracing are not considered, in detail, in these Design Guidelines." If the plans you submit to the city are approved, then no. Otherwise you have to do some math. The only thing that even mentions *free standing* is a stair case.

> LATERAL  BRACING  –  Is  a  system  within  the  porch  structure  to  prevent  lateral  movement  such  as  racking  and  possible  collapse.    Many, if not most, porches rely on the buildings that they are attached to for lateral stability.  Therefore, the porch structures must be securely attached  to  the  main  buildings  through  the  ledger  beams  or  other  means.    However,  even  with  attachment  to  the  main  building  the  outstanding or free edge of the porch structure must be braced.  This is especially  true  of  stair  structures  that  are  constructed  at  the  edge  of  the main porch platforms or decks.  (See Drawing 1D for a plan of this type of porch.)

> The forces that can cause racking of a porch structure are wind loads, vibration  and  impact  from  porch  use  and  out  of  plumb  framing.    Because  these  forces  can  occur  or  impinge  on  any  porch  structure,  every  porch  structure  must  be  designed  and  constructed  to  include  a  lateral  bracing  system.    **The  lateral  bracing  system  must  be  designed  to  resist  a  lateral  load  equal  to  at  least  the  wind  load  plus  2%  of  the  gravity dead and live loads.**  The minimum wind load is defined as 20 pounds per square foot (psf) in the Chicago Building Code.

> Lateral  bracing  is  therefore  most  commonly  found  on  the  face  of  the  porch  structure  that  is  parallel  to  the  rear  wall  of  the  building.    This  is  also considered to be the free edge(s) of the porch platform(s).  X, K or inverted V bracing is commonly used for this purpose as are diagonal braces  at  the  corners  of  posts  and  beams.    The  X,  K  or  inverted  V  bracing  carries  the  lateral  load  from  the  various  levels  of  the  porch  to  the ground.

> As the building is typically considered adequate to provide some lateral support,   no   bracing   is   usually   considered   necessary   to   prevent   movement  perpendicular  to  the  rear  wall  of  the  building.    It  is  also  possible, with some porch configurations, to brace the porch structure with diagonal bracing in the plane of the decks.  If the porch decks are designed  to  act  as  horizontal  diaphragms,  then  it  is  possible  for  the  entire  structure  to  be  adequately  braced  using  the  stability  of  the  building.    Bracing  of  decks  can  be  accomplished  by  the  use  of  dimension  lumber  attached  diagonally  under  the  joists  and  beams.    Furthermore,  decks  can  be  turned  into  diaphragms  by  installing  the  deck boards on a 45 degree angle.

> Because of the multitude of porch configurations in the City of Chicago and  many  possible  bracing  configurations,  specific  methods  of  lateral  bracing are not considered, in detail, in these Design Guidelines.